# Python PyQt4 update data on widget every 1 min

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I have a `PyQT4` application that reads information from a local `sqlite3` database and display the data using `QTableWidget`.

The data stored on the `sqlite3` changes from time to time.So, I want to update my Table Widget once every 1 min.

To simplify matters, let's assume i already have a function called '**Refresh()**' that will refresh the contents in my Table Widget.

How do i make this function '**Refresh()'** to execute every 1 min? I have done this in `Tkinter` using `time.after()`. I have no idea how to do it in `PyQt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function should probably be called **paintEvent**. Then make a [QTimer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html) like so:

```
self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
self.timer.start(60000) #trigger every minute.
```

That is unless you need to for some reason update something in the backed and not in the front end (in other words the function is **not** used for drawing. Otherwise it should allmost without question be called *paintEvent*). Then do:

```
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Refresh)
```

Comment: will this by any chance freeze my GUI or will it put the `paintEvent` queue in the event loop every 1 min?

Comment: @ChrisAung No it will not freeze, it will run as a part of your event loop. Liked to relevant docs.

Comment: depending on what self.update does it should not freeze the GUI.